# Is $\sqrt{|x|}$ uniformly continuous from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

> Is $\sqrt{|x|}$ uniformly continuous from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?

I can see it is continuous and by the derivative test it is not lipschitz but I can not prove (or disprove) uniformity.

Comment: If you don't need to explicitly furnish a modulus of continuity, here's a tip: it is Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R} \setminus [-1,1]$, now what happens on $[-1,1]$?

Comment: $$|\sqrt{|x|}-\sqrt{|y|}|\leq\sqrt{||x|-|y||}\leq\sqrt{|x-y|},\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If $x,y\geq 0$, prove that:

$$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\leq\sqrt{|x-y|}.$$

I let you adapt it when $x,y\in\mathbb R$.